# Javascript функция для каждого частичного представления mvc

Tags: javascript, mvc

Возникла проблема при попытке выполнения Javascript функции в частичном представлении.
Есть html страница следующего содержания:

```
@model ModelList

...
<div>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.Items)
    {
        @Html.Partial("PartialPage", item)
    }
</div>
...
```

На странице частичного представления, кроме всего прочего, выполняется javascript функция:

```
<div>
     <div id="text"></div>
</div>

<script>    
    function MyFunction() {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = @Model.Name;            
    }

    timer = setInterval(MyFunction, 1000);
</script>
```

При выполнении приложения javascript выполняется только для первого в списке частичного представления.

Как реализовать вывод для каждого пункта?

Comment: в ModelList например 5 элементов. что оказывается в html в браузере? 5-ть `<script>function MyFunction() {}</script>`? если да, то они запускаются почти одновременно.

Comment: и судя по `document.getElementById` в html несколько тегов с одинаковыми id="text"

Comment: а какой вообще результат от выполнения этих скриптов ожидается?

Comment: В данном случае нужен вывод оставшегося времени до завершения события. Скрипт берет информацию из базы данных по времени начала и продолжительности (через передаваемую модельку), считает время до завершения и выводит счетчик. Если добавить в ModelList пять элементов, то на странице оказывается пять событий, но только у первого выводится счетчик. Похоже, Вы абсолютно правы по поводу одинаковых тегов на странице. Вот она ошибка. Огромное спасибо.